# Overwriting an existing value in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewdidload

Is there anybody out there who could help me with a problem? I'm helping a friend with a game and we're stuck on how to overwrite an existing integer. The problem is with Objective-C in xCode.

There are two viewControllers frontPage and secondPage. In the frontPage we assign 100 to the startingScore in the viewDidLoad method. Then we go out to the secondPage and from the secondPage we come back. We want to use the startingScore from the secondPage in frontPage, but it's getting overwritten with viewDidLoad.

This is what we have from frontPage (or first View Controller):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    startingScore = 100;
    mylabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", startingScore];
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"Current value of newscore is: %d",startingScore);

}
```

This the code from the SecondViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    frontPage *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    destination.startingScore = 5000;
    destination.mylabel2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", destination.startingScore];
    NSLog(@"Current Value of destination.newscore is: %d",destination.startScore);  
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks,

Sam x.

Comment: Hi.. can you please show us how you declared startingScore?

Comment: Hi, sure this is from the frontPage viewController files: property (nonatomic) int startingScore; .h file and from the .m file: synthesize startingScore; Thanks,

Comment: This will be a lot easier to manage if you move your data model out of your view controller. Make a separate class to track the score, and have your owe controller retrieve & display the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the clue. Here you are changing value of `startingScore` 2 times. First you are setting its value to 500 in `viewDidLoad` . Then you are changing from 500 to 5000 in `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method. Now when you are coming back to `frontpage`, the `viewDidLoad` method is being called again for `frontPage`. so  value of `startingscore` is again turning into 500. You can check it by using `NSLog` function. I am pretty sure that's what happening here.

**Suggestions to rectify the problem**

1. Initiate `startingScore` in `init` of `frontPage`
2. Manage  `startingScore` from another class.

**Edit**  Just paste code written below in VC of your `FrontPage` & remove `startingScore = 500;` from your `viewDidLoad` Method

```
- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
 {
        startingScore = 500;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes that's whats happening, but we can't work out how to get around this problem? Sam x

Comment: I've Updated the answer. Check it & let me know

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help. I'll let you know how we get on. Sam x.

Comment: Hi, sorry having a blonde moment. Can you show a little bit more as to how we're going to get this to work? Thanks Sam x.

Comment: Sure. Can you come on chat now? will try to help you @user3162972

Comment: Oops. seems you can't. you need atleast 20 rep. Tell me what exactly you want to know.. :(

Comment: Really... I thought this was suppose to help you and you need 20 to chat. Sam x

Comment: Can you PLEASE!! help us out... Just a simple example of how to get round this problem. I just need to get this sort it's so annoying! How to take one int from frontPage and then change the score in secondPage and then send it back to frontPage? Thanks Sam x

Comment: Just as above our first problem. Thank Sam x

Answer (score 1):

If you want `startingScore` to be set to 100 when the frontPage view controller is first created and managed elsewhere from then on, you can move initialization of `startingScore` into your `init` function:

```
- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        // ...
        startingScore = 100;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code above would be called in our example, secondPage?  Sam x

Comment: @user3162972 I've updated the answer to be more clear that the code goes in the frontPage `init` method.